# Easier ways to solve complicated differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

I have a differential equation which looks like:

```
r'[l] = Sqrt[g11[r[l]]*gtt[r[l]] - g11[r0]*gtt[r0]]/
Sqrt[grr[r[l]]*gtt[r[l]]*g11[r[l]]]
```

I want to find the r[l]. I tried using DSolve

```
DSolve[{r'[l] == Sqrt[g11[r[l]]*gtt[r[l]] - g11[r0]*gtt[r0]]/
     Sqrt[grr[r[l]]*gtt[r[l]]*g11[r[l]]], r[0] == r0}, r[l], l]
```

But it is taking very long for my computer to solve. If anyone has any idea how to solve such differential equation, please let me know. Thanks.

My values for all the term:

```
$Assumptions[Inequality[r[l], GreaterEqual, r0, Greater, 1], Element[{a, B}, Reals]]
gtt[r_] = (-r^2)*Exp[2*As[r]]*g[r]; 
g11[r_] = r^2*Exp[2*As[r]]*h[r]; 
grr[r_] = Exp[2*As[r]]/(r^2*g[r]); 
g[r_] = 1 - (Exp[(3*a - B^2)*(1/r^2)]*(3*(a/r^2) - B^2/r^2 - 1) + 1)/
     (Exp[(3*a - B^2)*(1/rh^2)]*(3*(a/rh^2) - B^2/rh^2 - 1) + 1); 
A[r_] = -(a/r^2); 
p[r_] = ((9*a - B^2)*Log[Sqrt[6*a^2 - B^4]*Sqrt[(6*a^2 - B^4)/r^2 + 9*a - B^2] + 
        6*(a^2/r) - B^4/r])/Sqrt[6*a^2 - B^4] + 
    (1/r)*Sqrt[(6*a^2 - B^4)/r^2 + 9*a - B^2] - 
    ((9*a - B^2)*Log[Sqrt[9*a - B^2]*Sqrt[6*a^2 - B^4]])/Sqrt[6*a^2 - B^4]; 
As[r_] = A[r] + Sqrt[1/6]*p[r]; 
h[r_] = 1;
```

Comment: Why not to use `NDSolve`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev My variable "l" takes all the real numbers and when i use NDSolve its giving  me an error  "non-numerical value at l==0".

Comment: If a solution is found, what will you do next with it?

Comment: It is highly unlikely that this problem has a symbolic solution.  To obtain a numerical solution, you must specify the values of all constants, e.g., `r0`, `rh`, `a`, and `B`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev  I am trying to find value of some coefficients which depends on this r[l] and further to determine eigen values of a Sturm-Liouville equation.

Comment: @bbgodfrey   Indeed, I have exact values of r0==1.08318, rh=1, a=0.15, and B=0. The value of r0 was calculation from the value of B.

Comment: With these values, `r'[l]` is zero, so the solution is constant.

Comment: @bbgodfrey `r'[l]` is zero only when `l=0`. Otherwise, we have terms that contain `r[l]` on the right-hand side.

Comment: If `r[l]` equals `r0` then `r'[l]` is zero, independent of `l`.  Thus, if `r[l]` starts equal to`r0`, it stays equal to `r0` as `l` changes.  You can verify this by executing `NDSolveValue[{r'[l] == Sqrt[g11[r[l]]*gtt[r[l]] - g11[r0]*gtt[r0]]/Sqrt[grr[r[l]]*gtt[r[l]]*g11[r[l]]], r[0] == r0}, 
 r[l], {l, 0, 10}]

Answer (score 0):

With no information about the metric tensor, the separation of variables yields

```
      Solve[dr/dl == Sqrt[g11[r]*gtt[r] - g11[r0]*gtt[r0]]/
                        Sqrt[grr[r]*gtt[r]*g11[r]], dl]

    dl -> (dr Sqrt[g11[r] grr[r] gtt[r]])/
               Sqrt[ g11[r] gtt[r] - g11[r0] gtt[r0]]
```

The integral cannot be solved, of course, symbolically

$$ l-l_0 = \int \frac{\sqrt{\text{g11}(r)\   \text{grr}(r) \ \text{gtt}(r)}}{\sqrt{\text{g11}(r)\  \text{gtt}(r)-\text{g11}(\text{r0}) \ \text{gtt}(\text{r0})}} \, dr$$

Insert functions and get the inverse

```
   InverseFunction[ Function[r,integral[r] ]][l-l_0]
```